# Spring Batch - Performance Tuning

Tags: performance, spring, spring-batch

We developed a spring batch application in which we have two flows. 1. Forward 2. Backward. We are only using file read/write no DB involved.

1. Forward Scenario : The input file will have records with 22 fields. The 22 fields to be converted into 32 fields by doing some operations like sequence number generation and adding few fillers fields. Based on country codes the output will be split into max 3. each chunk will have 250K records. (If records are  in million the multiple files will be generated for same country).

   8 Million records its taking 36 minutes.

   8 Million records will be in single file.

   We are using spring batch thread 1000 threads we are using.
2. Backward Flow : The input file will have 82 fields for each record. These 82 fields to be converted into 86 records. The two fields will be added in between which is taken from the Forward flow input file. The other fields are simply copied and pasted. The error records also to be written into error file. The error records is nothing but actual input records which came for Forward flow. To track we are persisting the sequence number & actual records in a file this is done in forward flow itself. We are taking the persistent file in backward flow and comparing the sequence number if anything is missing then we are writing into error records through key,value pair. This process is done after completion of backward flow.

   Maximum size of input file is 250K.

   8 Million records its taking 1 hour 8 minutes which is too bad. 
     32 Files (each 250K) will be there for input in this flow. 
     There is  no thread used in backward. I don't know how thread usage will be. I tried but the process got hung.

Server Configurations:

- 12 CPU & 64 GB Linux Server.

  Can you guys help in this regard to get improved the performance since we have 12 CPU/64GB RAM.

Comment: Govind, your question is quite generic and does not have enough data to suggest anything. I would suggest you use profilers like jProfiler, Visual VM etc to monitor your JVM as well as code and see if that leads to somethin g useful!

Answer (score 0):

You are already using 1000 threads and that is a very high number. I have fine tuned spring batch jobs and this is what I have done
1. Reduce network traffic- Try to reduce number of calls to data base or file system in each process. Can you get all info possible in one shot and save it in memory for the life of thread ? I have uses org.apache.commons.collections.map.MultiKeyMap for storage and retrieval of data.
For eg in your case you need sequence number comparison . So get all sequence numbers into one map before you start the process. You can store the ids (if not too many) into step execution context.

1. Write less frequently - Keep storing all the info you need to write for some time and then write them at the end.
2. Set unused objects at end of process to null to expedite GC
3. Check your GC frequency through VisualVm or Jconsole . You should see frequent GC happening when your process is running which means objects are being created and garbage collected. If your memory graph keeps on increasing, something is wrong.